# Visual Studio Express 2012 Editions - Exe names and registry path?

Tags: visual-studio, express, visual-studio-2012

In short I'm looking for the **executable names** and **registry paths** to the InstallDir key for each of the Visual Studio 2012 Express editions.

They are (minus the RC label)

- Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8
- Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web
- Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2012

The registry path will be in the HKLM hive and be something like:

> {HKLM}\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\????\11.0

The executable names is probably different for each edition if previous versions of VS Express are anything to go by.

For completeness, here's the `edition number`, `version`, `solution version` and `HKLM relative registry path` of each of the previous versions of Visual Studio .Net from 2002 up to 2012.

```
public class VSType
{
    public VSType(){}
    public VSType(string edition, string version, string solutionVersion, string hklmRegistryPath) {/*...*/}
    public static VSType VS2002 = new VSType("2002", "7.0", "7.00", "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\7.0");
    public static VSType VS2003 = new VSType("2003", "7.10", "8.00", "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\7.1");
    public static VSType VS2005 = new VSType("2005", "8.0", "9.00", "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\8.0");
    public static VSType VS2008 = new VSType("2008", "9.0", "10.00", "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\9.0");
    public static VSType VS2010 = new VSType("2010", "10.0", "11.00", "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\10.0");
    public static VSType VS2012 = new VSType("2012", "11.0", "12.00", "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\11.0");
}

public class VSExpressType : VSType
{
    public VSExpressType(VSType vsType, string name, string exeName, string hklmRegistryPath) {/*...*/}

    // 2005  ***********************************************************************
    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2005CSharp = new VSExpressType(VS2005,
        "Microsoft Visual C# 2005 Express Edition",
        "VCSExpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VCSExpress\\8.0");

    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2005VB = new VSExpressType(VS2005,
        "Microsoft Visual Basic 2005 Express Edition",
        "vbexpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VBExpress\\8.0");

    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2005Web = new VSExpressType(VS2005,
        "Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition",
        "VWDExpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VWDExpress\\8.0");

    // 2008  ***********************************************************************
    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2008CSharp = new VSExpressType(VS2008,
        "Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition",
        "VCSExpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VCSExpress\\9.0");

    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2008VB = new VSExpressType(VS2008,
        "Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition",
        "vbexpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VBExpress\\9.0");

    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2008Web = new VSExpressType(VS2008,
        "Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition",
        "VWDExpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VWDExpress\\9.0");

    // 2010  ***********************************************************************
    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2010CSharp = new VSExpressType(VS2010,
        "Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express Edition",
        "VCSExpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VCSExpress\\10.0");

    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2010VB = new VSExpressType(VS2010,
        "Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition",
        "vbexpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VBExpress\\10.0");

    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2010Web = new VSExpressType(VS2010,
        "Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Edition",
        "VWDExpress.exe",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VWDExpress\\10.0");

    // 2012 ***********************************************************************
    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2012WIn8 = new VSExpressType(VS2012,
        "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8",
        "EXENAME",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\REGISTRYPATH");

    public static VSExpressType VSExpress2012Web = new VSExpressType(VS2012,
        "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web",
        "EXENAME",
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\REGISTRYPATH");

    public static VSExpressType VSExpressTFS2012 = new VSExpressType(VS2012,
                "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2012",
                "EXENAME",
                "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\REGISTRYPATH");
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this?  These are private registry keys used by VS, they never affect anything you develop.  Especially the Express editions since they are not licensed to support add-ons.

Comment: The point is that I can look up the install location using the InstallDir registry entry so that I can determine what version(s) of VS are installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8**

- Exe Name: `VSWinExpress.exe`
- Reg Path: `{HKLM}\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VSWinExpress\\11.0`

**Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web**

- Exe Name: `VWDExpress.exe`
- Reg Path: `{HKLM}\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VWDExpress\\11.0`

**Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2012**

- ExeName: `TfsMgmt.exe` for the Management console
- Reg Path: `{HKLM}\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundationServer\\11.0`

Note that there is no `InstallDir` directly under the TFS\11 path. Instead there's an `InstalledComponents` node with a list of compents that are installed and InstallPath keys for each.

Also note that on 64 bit PCs, the keys will be under the `{HKLM}\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\` node.

Comment: In my experience this is actually under HKCU and not HKLM.

Comment: Both HKLM and HKCU hives exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows Phone:
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VPDExpress.exe"
2. Desktop:
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe"